# Problem receiving data from API and assigning it to model

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I have a method that makes an asynchronous call to an API, the structure of the data that the API returns is identical to the model I want to assign. However it never loads the object. The data is always null, but if there is a response from the API and if it delivers the data, but does not assign it to the variable: `podcast`.

The purpose of this method is to pass the data to view.
(I use .Net core 5 in a Web Project)

this is my method

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> details(int id)
    {
        if (id != 0)
        {
            //Read Service for config Metas 
            PPodcast podcast = new PPodcast();

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{_storageOption.devVirtualPath}{_endpoints.ObtenerPodcast}" + id))
                {
                    string apiResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    podcast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PPodcast>(apiResponse);
                }
            }
            ViewBag.idPodcast = id;
            return View(podcast);

        }
        return View(null);
    }
```

This is my model:

```
 public class PPodcast
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int idSeccion { get; set; }
    public string titulo { get; set; }
    public string descripcion { get; set; }
    public string contenido { get; set; }
    public string embeb { get; set; }
    public string imagenRef { get; set; }
    public string tags { get; set; }
    public string fecha_PE { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Hora { get; set; }
    public string urlPodcast { get; set; }
    public string SeccionNombre { get; set; }
    
}
```

Comment: Please show us some actual content of `apiResponse`

Comment: Hi, this is a part of response
"{\"data\":{\"id\":34,\"idSeccion\":2,\"titulo\":\"Peruano que trabaja en Facebook impulsa Techsuyo\",\"

Comment: `return View(null);` shouldn't that be `return View(podcast)`?

Comment: Or if I'm sorry it was a typo, but that's not the problem, the problem is that the return of the data is not assigned to the variable "podcast"

Comment: yes it is wrong, according to your response, **PPodcast** is nested inside **data** part of the json, you are not pointing that out to the deserilizer so it doesn't understand it

Comment: Hello, and how do I solve it? or how do I modify the method so that the data is effectively assigned to the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if all of your responses have the same shape, it is better to create a generic class that contains the classes you want

example:

```cs
public class Response<T> 
{
    public T Data {  get; set; }
    // additional items like errors and such
}
```

then in your deserilizer you would use it as such

```cs
podcast = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response<PPodcast>>(apiResponse).Data;
```

Comment: I'm testing it, but em says that you can't implicitly convert the Response type to Podcast

Comment: fixed a typo in code, now it should work

Comment: Now it works perfect. I am very grateful for your collaboration and your time. Thank you so much

Comment: great, please mark it as answered

Comment: Can you guide me in which part I mark it as answered? please

Comment: Ok thanks @hoshani